# How to make sure the process of updating a firebase database is completed regardless of activity's lifecycle

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

My app has an activity that shows a news article and it has a bookmark ImageButton. When clicked, the method shown below is called

```
 public void onBookmarkClick(View view){
    if (isBookmarked){
        bookmarkedDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Article articleValue = snapshot.getValue(Article.class);
                    String id = snapshot.getKey();
                    if (article.equals(articleValue)){
                        bookmarkedDatabase.child(id).removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }else {
        String id = bookmarkedDatabase.push().getKey();
        bookmarkedDatabase.child(id).setValue(article);
    }
    isBookmarked = !isBookmarked;
    setupBookmarkIcon();
}
```

But when I rotate the screen or press back button **immediately** after clicking *bookmark* button, the article isn't added to bookmarks.

How do I make sure that the process of reading and writing from/ to a firebase database is complete even when activity is being destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use complete Listener to know if your update is successful or not . From firebase documentation

```
Add a Completion Callback
If you want to know when your data has been committed, you can add a completion listener. 
Both setValue() and updateChildren() take an optional completion 
listener that is called when 
the write has been successfully committed to the database. 
If the call was unsuccessful, the listener is passed an error object indicating why the failure occurred
```

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Or my suggestion to use viewModel class and do update from there.

[Viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)